# DEFAULT_REPORT_FIELDS cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, acra

using acra, the following code does not compile with error

DEFAULT_REPORT_FIELDS cannot be resolved or is not a field

```
private Map<String, String> remap(Map<ReportField, String> report) {  
      ReportField[] fields = ACRA.getConfig().customReportContent();  
      if (fields.length == 0) {  
           fields = ACRA.DEFAULT_REPORT_FIELDS;
         }  
      final Map<String, String> finalReport = new HashMap<String, String>(  
                report.size());  
      for (ReportField field : fields) {  
           if (mMapping == null || mMapping.get(field) == null) {  
                finalReport.put(field.toString(), report.get(field));  
           } else {  
                finalReport.put(mMapping.get(field), report.get(field));  
           }  
      }  
      return finalReport;  
 }
```

Comment: This has already been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25340239/493682

Answer (score 0):

That must be for an old(er) version. Try this instead:

```
ACRAConstants.DEFAULT_REPORT_FIELDS
```